# Extract am or pm in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have date in following manner -

```
06:04:51 am
```

I want to extract `am/pm` from this date time. 
Based upon the am or pm will select particular class in time-holder.

Is there any way to extract the value?

Comment: is it a string? or you have a date object?

Comment: Might be overkill in the context of this single issue, but if you are working with dates/times, I would recommend taking a look at [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) - a fantastic library for dealing with dates.

Comment: If you are using or have access to a date object to go along with the time you can just check the hours (`myDate.getHours()>=12?"PM":"AM"`)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string cut last 2 characters.

```js
var date = '06:04:51 am';
var ampm = date.slice(-2);
console.log(ampm);
```

if It's a date object

```js
var date = new Date();

console.log(getAMPM(date));

function getAMPM(dateObj) {
  return dateObj.getHours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex to get the am or pm
from the string

```
"06:04:51 am".match(/(am|pm)/gi)
["am"]

"06:04:51 pm".match(/(am|pm)/gi)
["pm"]
```

Using case insensitive flag ensures that it matches AM,PM also

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this to extract the `am` or `pm` after space

```
var str="06:04:51 am";
alert(str.substr(str.indexOf(" ") + 1));
```